# Setting up Subnetwork for Free Wifi Only

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I have a Linksys WRT-54GL router (192.168.0.1/24) with DHCP enabled (DHCP-Start: 192.168.0.80 - DHCP-End: 192.168.0.180). = NETWORK (A)

In this network are office computers.

I want to add to this network a TP-Link TL-WR1043ND Wifi router (static IP inside (A) network: 192.168.0.200 / Getway-Address: 10.10.10.10) width DHCP enabled (DHCP-Start: 10.10.10.11 - DHCP-End: 10.10.10.250) = NETWORK (B)

WIFI clients connected to network (B) should not be able to access network (A) clients and servers etc. - but should be able to connect to the internet over the WRT-54GL router from network (A).

```
Internet
||||||||
(A) WRT-54GL --- clients and servers from network (A)
||||||||
(B) TP-Link  --- only wifi clients (not allowed to access network (A))
```

What are the steps to set this up? What should I mention?

Comment: Even if you can set this up, i think you are going the wrong way. Clients on network B can always hack their way to network A by changing their ip. You would better go for internet directly to B and connect router-A via the WAN-port to B. That way clients from B can't get (easy) access to A.

Comment: i know that @Rik 's comment would be the best one. but it is not possible to do that. can (B) also get into the (A) network, when the TP-Link router is over the WAN-Port connected with network (A)? is it possible to add an direct routing from 192.168.0.1 to 10.10.10.10? or doesn't make this any sense?

Comment: If you connect router-B with its WAN-port to router-A it would be safe(r). The router will probably block all non-internet traffic (but i'm not 100% sure of the inner workings of a router).

Comment: Just connect router-B (with its WAN-port) to router-A (normal internal port) and setup router-B to get an (external-)ip from the DHCP from A and your good to go. No need to set the internal ip of B to a static-external address.

Comment: And if you want to be sure (besides connecting to the WAN port) maybe you can block all access to 192.168.0.1/24 in router B.

Comment: thank you @Rik. but when A gives router B an IP over DHCP - I only know the router B IP address by looking into the DHCP table of router A. wouldn't it be better so make a static IP for router B?

Comment: Why would you want to know the external IP of router B. You don't need it for anything. You can't access it from router A and network B does not need to know the external ip of B because they get an ip from the DHCP from B. (and if you're curious you can check the web-interface :)